# Listening to notifications on background and start the app

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

As documented on react-native-firebase docs(https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages) we can register an headlessTask and listen to notifications while the application is on the background.
Sadly I haven't found a way of starting the app on foreground once a FCM notification is received on the background mode, is this possible?
Below is the code displayed at react-native-firebase for listening to notifications on the background

**bgMessaging.js**

```js
// @flow
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
    // handle your message

    return Promise.resolve();
}

//This handler method must return a promise and resolve within 60 seconds.
```

**index.js**

```js
import bgMessaging from './src/bgMessaging'; // <-- Import the file you created in (2)

// Current main application
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeFirebaseDemo', () => bootstrap);
// New task registration
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging); // <-- Add this line
```

Any help would be really helpfull

Comment: Users need to tap the notification icon in order to start the app AFAIK

Comment: @aytek that's bad, this is a voip application, we should start the app if an incoming call is coming, on ios we use push kit to solve it, not sure if there's a similar option for android

Answer (score 1):

Use the following library to start your app when you receive the notification:
https://github.com/lvlrSajjad/react-native-launch-application

e.g In your ** bgMessaging** do:

```
//PackageName Must Be String For example "com.domain.application"
export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
    SajjadLaunchApplication.open(".domain.application");
}
```

Comment: this does start the app but not in foreground, it opens the app directly, which will be probably not possible in incoming android version, also is not what im looking for, I want to start it in foreground and keep it there

Comment: It will bring the app to foreground and show it even if the screen is locked